# Skype - How to use flash or flex or action script?

Tags: .net, apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, air

Question. How can i get started with flash/flex or actionscript, to use the Skype4Com, and make something small like this site: https://imo.im/

1. After login with my SkypID, i can make a voice call from browser using Flash? How, can i get started on this, can someone show me a way please.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this a COM Object?

If so, you can't access it from Flex directly and won't be able to access it in a browser based app at all.  Your best bet is going to be to take a look at AIR 2 and the [NativeProcess](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/flex/quickstart/interacting_with_native_process.html).  I believe you'll still need to write some form of bridge in either Java or .NEt to act as a proxy between the Skype library and Flex.

Comment: Thank you, I went to the link, seems like too much complicated resource out there. Who just want to start from the begin. 

You have any working example of AIR2 + NativeProcess and Mix cocktail of .NET which can just do a hello world? 

Would be a nice getting started resource here.

Comment: I don't have a sample, haven't dealt with it personally.  But, if I were to start I'd be looking at the documentation on NativeProcess and articles from Adobe like the one I linked to.

Answer (score 0):

www.flextras.com is correct. You will need to use a bridge like Merapi w/ Air. Here is a link that might point you in the right direction.

http://casario.blogs.com/mmworld/2009/01/accessing-skype-through-an-air-app-using-merapi-and-creating-different-bindings-based-on-different-e.html

http://blog.comtaste.com/2009/01/how_to_enable_communication_be_1.html